# Why is the date "2012-12-01" causing printed table to repeat it over and over?

Tags: php, mysql

I know this one is strange. I have a table called `schedule` with a column called `Date` with the column type being `DATE`. I have dates (in YYYY-MM-DD format) from 2012-11-01 to 2013-01-02 in this column. What's happening is if I enter a date, any date, that has 2012-12-01 anywhere in between, it restarts the loop. So if I select 2012-11-15 to 2012-12-15 it will print from Novemeber 15th to December 1st, but then after December 1st it starts printing again at November 15th. If I select 2012-11-15 to 2012-11-30 or 2012-12-02 to 2012-12-30 everything works fine, it's just when that particular date is involved that it causes problems. Here is my code:

```
<?php
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////First set the date range that we want to use//////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

if(isset($_POST['from']) && ($_POST['from'] != NULL))
    {
    $startDate = $_POST['from'];
    echo "<script>alert (\"startDate: " . $startDate . "\")</script>";
    }
else
    {
    //Default date is Today
    $startDate = date("Y-m-d");
    echo "<script>alert (\"startDate: " . $startDate . "\")</script>";
    }
if(isset($_POST['to']) && ($_POST['to'] != NULL))
    {
    $endDate = $_POST['to'];
    echo "<script>alert (\"endDate: " . $endDate . "\")</script>";
    }
else
    {
    //Default day is one month from today
    $endDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 month"));
    echo "<script>alert (\"endDate: " . $endDate . "\")</script>";
    }

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////Next calculate the total amount of days selected above to use as a limiter//////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    $dayStart = strtotime($startDate);
    $dayEnd = strtotime($endDate);
    $total_days = abs($dayEnd - $dayStart) / 86400 +1;
    echo "<script>alert (\"Total Days: " . $total_days . "\")</script>";

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////Then we're going to get the date range specified from the schedule table and print the results//////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//Select the dates from the schedule table, limited to the total amount days.
$sql = ("SELECT Date FROM schedule WHERE Date BETWEEN '$startDate' AND '$endDate' LIMIT $total_days");

//Run a check on the query to make sure it worked. If it failed then print the error.
if(!$result_date_query = $mysqli->query($sql))
    {
    die('There was an error getting the date from the schedule table [' . $mysqli->error . ']');
    }

//Loop through the results while a result is being returned.
while($row = $result_date_query->fetch_assoc())
    {
    //First format and then print the all the dates selected.
    echo "<td class=\"schedule_date_cell\">" . date('M j', strtotime($row['Date'])) . "</td>";
    }

//Free the result.
$result_date_query->free();
?>
```

I am at a loss. I've added in some echo statements to show what's going on and everything is as expected. I just don't understand how all dates before and all dates after work perfectly, but anything that has Dec 1st in it makes it restart the loop. I'm not sure if it's relevant, but there are multiples of the same dates in the column, which is why I have set `LIMIT` in the query.

I'm hoping someone can crack this case wide open as I'm dying to know the answer!

**EDIT: **I tried this same query from within PHPmyadmin as suggested in the comments, and it produces the same results. I also tried removing the `LIMIT` as well as changing from single quotes `'2012-11-01'` to double quotes `"2012-11-01"` with still the same results.

**EDIT2: **For each date in the `Date` column, there are 92 instances of each date. So, for example, there are 92 records of 2012-12-01 and 92 records of 2012-12-02 and so on. The interesting thing is, when I remove `LIMIT` from the query and use the date range of 2012-11-30 to 2012-12-15 (Nov 30th to Dec 15th) is prints Nov 29th, Nov 30th, Dec 1st then repeats those three dates again and again, 92 times! Then after that it starts to print the rest of the days Dec 2nd, Dec 3rd, Dec 4th ...Dec 15th and then repeats THOSE dates again and again, 92 times! This just proves that for some reason the loop is restarting at Dec 1st because if I enter a date range of Nov 1st to Nov 3rd it prints all dates in the range before repeating itself 92 times. The reason for the `LIMIT` was so to stop it from returning all instances of each date, so I would only get Nov 1st to Nov 3rd one time and not 92 times, but when the limit is removed we can see that Dec 1st is causing some weird issues.

**EDIT3: **I created a new table `schedule2` identical to `schedule` and entered the same date range of 2012-11-01 to 2013-01-02, but this time with only one instance of each. Then I ran my query again and it works perfectly, in any date combination. So obviously the problem is that there is more than one instance of this date in the `schedule` table, but I can't figure out WHY it's a problem. I don't understand what this date is having an affect on the `while` loop. And before you suggest it, yes, I do need to have multiple instances of the same date in the table ;)

Comment: have you tried the same query in `phpmyadmin`? just try with it.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar I just tried it now and it does that exact same thing!! What could be causing this?

Comment: Andrew this shows that your code is correct and query also. I think this is occurring because of the data present inside table. I will suggest to change the datatype of `Date` column to `DATETIME` OR `TIMESTAMP`. Try with it.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar I just changed it to `DATETIME` and tried running the query again, same results. If I change it to `TIMESTAMP` it will automatically update the column with the current time stamp, which I don't want.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar "Andrew this shows that your code is correct and query also" how is this true? Didn't he try it in phpMyAdmin, and it gave him the same error as above? Meaning it's a problem with the query?

Comment: @Charlie andrew said that he tried it in phpmyadmin.

Comment: @Charlie that is a good point. But the query is pretty solid, isn't it? It just seems to be that one date that messes everything up, my query works great with any other date combination.

Comment: Right but a wrong query could still be a problem, even it it runs okay. But I agree with @YogeshSuthar on it being the content. Although I don't know why the query's not working with `12` as the month.

Comment: @Charlie but that's the thing, the month being 12 is ok, because it works for every other day in December, just not the 1st.

Comment: Try `SELECT DISTINCT(Date) FROM schedule WHERE Date BETWEEN '$startDate' AND '$endDate' ORDER BY Date ASC`

Comment: @WillemRenzema YESSSSSS!!! That did it!!! Brilliant!! Oh how happy you have made me! Thank you SO much! Now, write that as an answer so I can accept it for you :))

Comment: Valuable lessons learned here today folks, thank you all.

Comment: Please, before you cause yourself severe harm, add some [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to this. You're taking in an arbitrary parameter and slamming it into your query without even using `mysql_real_escape_string` on it. You shouldn't even be using `mysql_query` for this very reason. It's extremely dangerous by default.

Comment: @tadman I know this isn't a good reason, but this is being created for internal use in my company, it will never see a public web server. Regardless, I normally do use a function called `mysql_slashes_prep` that uses the `mysql_real_escape_string` as well as determines the status of `magicquotes` and goes from there. This isn't the first time I've had someone remind me of this, and regardless of if it's going on a public server or not, I really should be adding this function into my code. Cheers!

Comment: I just noticed you're using `mysqli`. You should *not* be using `mysql_real_escape_string` in this case but instead make use of the simple [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) interface. It's hardly a line of code more and immesurably safer. You should not mix `mysql_real_escape_string` and `mysqli`.

Comment: @tadman This is actually my first project using `mysqli`, so thanks for the advice, I probably wouldn't have noticed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that it loops at Dec 1st is for the most part just a coincidence. I don't know the specifics of how MySQL works internally, but if you don't give it an order, then it will apply whatever order it feels like to the data when you request it.

Combine this with the fact that you have duplicate dates, and then you end up with the situation have you described spontaneously happening for no apparent reason.

Since you want each date exactly once, and you want them to appear in order chronologically, then you need to tell MySQL you want those two things when you make the query. As such, add `DISTINCT` AND `ORDER BY` commands:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(Date) FROM schedule WHERE Date BETWEEN '$startDate' AND '$endDate' ORDER BY Date ASC
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to use a `LIMIT` clause. Instead, change your query to make sure it does not return any dates more than once:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(Date) FROM schedule WHERE Date BETWEEN '$startDate' AND '$endDate'
```

That will give you each date just once.

You probably have an index on the `Date` column (which is good), and the index sorts all dates in November before dates in December (at least for the same year). And you would have the same issue for date ranges that start in December and end in January.

Answer (score 0):

You could have prevented the duplication by adding a `UNIQUE` index on the columns that define an entry for a particular date.

This is pretty easy to add after the fact if you've cleaned up your data to remove duplicates:

```
ALTER TABLE schedule ADD UNIQUE INDEX index_on_date (date)
```

The alternative is to select only one row per date, which usually amounts to appending `GROUP BY date` at the end of your query.

Comment: As mentioned in my original post, I actually do need it to have more than one of the same date in that column. The `GROUP BY` option is a good idea, but because of the other columns in the table, it wouldn't work in this case. Thanks though.

Comment: You can group on multiple columns to define what set of rows you want to fetch. It's up to you to specify what qualifies as "unique enough".